# Write Excel from template with XLSX Angular

Tags: angular, npm, base64, xlsx

I'm using XLSX library in an Angular application to write an Excel file from another file. My initial file is encoded in base64 so I need to decode it and modify some cells. Next, I have to save this new file in base64.

```
                const byteArray = new Uint8Array(
                  atob(files[0].base64Content)
                        .split('')
                        .map((char) => char.charCodeAt(0))
                );

                const file = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'text/csv' });
                const imageFile = new File([file], files[0].fileName, {
                    type: 'text/csv',
                });

                let fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(imageFile);
                fileReader.onload = (e) => {
                    var arrayBuffer: any = fileReader.result;
                    var data = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
                    var arr = new Array();
                    for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i)
                        arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);

                    var bstr = arr.join('');
                    var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });
                    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets['Worksheet1'];

                    worksheet['BP3'] = 'x';
              };
```

I read the sheet and changed the value of a cell. I would now need to save this file in base64. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "XLSX library", you mean [SheetsJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx), in which case, I believe what you are looking for is the `writeFile` method (found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#writing-workbooks)). You can use the `type` [option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#output-type) as a part of the options argument.

```
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, files[0], { type: 'base64' })
```

Comment: I noticed that I lose cell formatting (color, font, etc.). How could this problem be remedied?

Comment: @manatale are you using the pro edition? Styling is only available in the pro edition afaik